# Python kivy. Something wrong with collide_widget or not?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to print different numbers depending on the location of widgets in kivy using method collide_widget. However, instead of printing 1 or 0 depending on if clause, I get 1 and 0 at the same time and I don't understand why. I have no idea where I am wrong. It would be nice if someone explained this to me.

Here is my code.

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<Sample@Image>:
    size: self.size
    allow_stretch: False
    keep_ratio: False
    do_rotation: False

<PutOnShelfScreen1>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'image.png'
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing: 30
        padding: [10, 150, 10, 10]
        Button:
            id: Tools
            background_color: [63, 191, 63, 0.3]
            text: ''
        Button:
            id: Transportation
            background_color: [63, 191, 63, 0.3]
            text: ''
        Button:
            id: Furniture
            background_color: [63, 191, 63, 0.3]
            text: ''

    StencilView:
        id: elka
        Scatter:
            pos: 500, 500
            size: my_image1.size
            Image:
                id: my_image1
                source: 'block_1\\ель.png'

    StencilView:
        id: armchair
        Scatter:
            pos: 500, 500
            size: my_image2.size
            Image:
                id: my_image2
                source: 'block_1\\armchair.png'
                on_touch_up: root.Count(Furniture, Tools, Transportation, armchair) 
''')

class PutOnShelfScreen1(Screen):
    Tools = Widget()
    Transportation = Widget()
    Furniture = Widget()

    armchair = Widget()

    def Count(self, Furniture, Tools, Transportation, armchair):
        if armchair.collide_widget(Furniture) is True:
            print("1")
        if armchair.collide_widget(Tools) or armchair.collide_widget(Transportation) is True:
            print("0")

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(PutOnShelfScreen1(name='class'))

class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return (sm)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SampleApp().run()
```

Comment: Your `Tools`, 'Transportation`, `Furniture`, and `armchair`  widgets that you create in your python code have nothing to do with the ids in your kv string.

Comment: I thought I tied widgets and python code already. Or did I misunderstood your comment?

Answer (score 0):

You have tied the kv and python code together, but you haven't correctly used that connection. Please read the `ids` section in the [widget documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html).

In your code, the call to `PutOnShelfScreen1(name='class')` creates an object with your specified `ids`. If you get a reference to that object like:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
poss1 = PutOnShelfScreen1(name='class')
sm.add_widget(poss1)
```

Then you can use `poss1` to access those widgets that you are interested in:

```
Tools = poss1.ids['Tools']
Transportation = poss1.ids['Transportation']
Furniture = poss1.ids['Furniture']
armchair = poss1.ids['armchair']
```